# Android SQLiteOpenHelper: Determining reason for onUpgrade exceptions

Tags: android, exception, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'd like to log any Exceptions that may be occurring on my app's onUpgrade method of SQLiteOpenHelper, so that I may fix any query issues in subsequent updates.

With regards to Exceptions, the documentation only mentions the following:

> This method executes within a transaction. If an exception is thrown,
> all changes will automatically be rolled back.

Does anyone have any idea on how I can go about determining why my onUpgrade method failed, in my Android app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your `onUpgrade()` in a `try`-`catch` that logs and rethrows the exception. Along the lines of:

```
try {
    db.execSQL(/* upgrades */);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    Log.w(TAG, "onUpgrade failed", t);
    throw t;
}
```

Comment: If I do it the way you suggest, then the App ends and if I catch and do not throw, then it tries to Commit. I have modified parts of my app to continue to work, if there is a onUpgrade failure and need to continue running my app and show the Error message as a warning.

Comment: If there's an issue in onUpgrade, that's a programming error and the best thing to do there is to crash (and not continue in some inconsistent state).

Comment: On a previous iteration, my app had a bug when the user would use an apostrophe. There may also be unexpected failed data integrity or relational integrity problems due to the nature of data. I agree proper testing is required, but I don't want the app to crash due to that.